# Ajax html data binding does not work in case of mobile devices preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I would like to ask about a *strange* problem which is happening to me.
The problem is that I have written a JQuery Ajax request to get Data from Server. In case of desktop Pc/Laptop  my browser successfully binds this *"Html" return data from the server on to the "DIV"* where I am trying binding it.

But now I have also written the same script for mobile devices In case of mobile devices/tablets I am getting the same data but at binding moment with Div my mobile browser shows blank page Even after loading menu's and logo from top but as long Ajax request gets the data it shows blank page.

For me it seems to be a CSS problem even if I use *`$('#mydivid').text(data)`* on mobile browser case it shows me the whole data but in textual form and it does not get blank as well.
Anyone have any thoughts about it could be helpful for me .

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: This is probably because the browser has JS disabled

Comment: How much time did you spend over-painting the info in the header, Mubashir?

Comment: Js is enabled in browser